# How to I set a Grid View Cell Value colour?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view that is populated dynamically through a stored procedure

**I would like to ask how can I loop through each row and set the colour of the value for column17 upon populating the gridview?
For example, for value range between 1 - 20 I would like to the colour to be green, value between 21-40 to be orange and 41 - 60 to be red?**

My codes to populate the gridview:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spretrieve, conn))
                {
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DATE;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Key;
string query = cmd.CommandText;

conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
Gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event of gridview:-

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           e.Row.Cells[16].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       }
 }
```

This will set the background color of all the rows in column `17`(I have used `16` since it's zero index based) to green except header. If you want to set the color of header as well then don't check the `DataRow` condition.

Also, if you want to color few range like from column 1-20 then you can use a `for` loop.

Comment: How does this loop and see the value if it belongs to the colour to be set?

Comment: @JamesBoer - Didn't get you, it loops for each row and we need to only worry about column that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to use

```
Row[xx].Cells[xx].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.xxx
```

in the databound event of the row. You can look up for available colors on the net.

hope it helps